# To find the power of the test against hypothesis test

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-writing, conditional-probability, hypothesis-testing

[image: click on picture to view]

This problem is all about probability density function and hypothesis which I am familiar with. But the problem is that I can't figure out how to approach the problem. A rigorous proof is needed. Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer, and let me know if it's understandable or not. However, after posting a problem, try to be patient and polite. Statements like "Has anyone even seen the problem" doesn't sound polite at all.

Comment: I was being too rash... I am sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a)** $~~$At first, we need to find the distribution of $X = \max(0 , Z)$ . Clearly, if $x < 0$ , then $F_X(x) = 0$ , and if $x \geqslant 0$ , $F_X(x) = F_Z(x)$ .

Therefore, given that $\mu = 0$ , for $x \geqslant 0$ , $$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{2}e^{-\vert z \vert} ~dz = \frac{1}{2} + \int_0^x \frac{1}{2}e^{-\vert z \vert}~dz = 1 - \frac{1}{2} e^{-x}$$ And, for $x < 0$ , we can see that $F_X(x) = 0 $ very clearly.

Since this is a one-tailed test, thus : $$F_X(c) = 0.95\quad\iff\quad e^{-c} = 0.1 \quad \iff\quad \boxed{~c = \log_e 10~}$$

---

**(b)** $~~$ Once (a) is done, (b) is straightforward. Power of the test will be : $$P(X > c~\vert~ \mu = 2) = F_X(c - 2) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} e^{-(\log_e 10 - 2)} = \boxed{~0.6305}$$

---

Hope this helps. Let me know if my answer is erroneous.

Comment: Hey Kolmogorov... Are you a student at ISI?

Comment: Well, maybe. Or, may be not. Why do you want to know ?

Comment: As in your bio... You have given UG student in statistics and your location in KOLKATA... So ISI is the best institute for statistics.all over India.. That's why

Comment: Haha, I'm flattered ! Anyway, please try not to ask this type of questions in comment section.

Answer (score -1):

In a very rigorous way it is enough  to apply the definitions.

(a) Find $c$ such that

$$P[X>c |\mu=0]=0.05$$

(b) Fixed $c$ found in (a), calculate

$$P[X>c|\mu=2]$$

These are the rigorous definitions of "size" and "power" . All you have to do is to do the calculations